# How to deal every TS file as an isolated module?

Tags: typescript, module

First off, I'm really a newbie in TS.

Second, in Dart every file in a same directory can be independently run, if you need any object from another file then you need explicitly import it. For example:

**file1.dart**

```
int myFunc() => 99;

void main() {
  print(myFunc());
}
```

**file2.dart**

```
import file1 as f1;

String myFunc() => 'Chesu!';

void main() {
  print(f1.myFunc());
  print(myFunc());
}
```

This don't raise any exception or error or warning messages, but in TS you cannot have two objects with the same name because they are **automatically** imported (or visible) for other files in the same directory. Is there any way to disable this feature?

Comment: Each file IS ENOUGH to have `export {}` to be a module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this option in `tsconfig.json` file:

```
 "moduleDetection": "force",
```